# How can I open a PDF file in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: file, pdf, microsoft-edge

I know that the easiest way to open a resource in Edge is by using the microsoft-edge: protocol handler. 
I think this works for html files. For instance, you could run microsoft-edge:http://stackoverflow.com to open Stack Overflow in Edge.

But, what if I want to open a PDF file? 
Can I run microsoft-edge:file:///C:/Desktop/sample.pdf ?
Looks like it's not working for me.

Thanks

Comment: When you say "it's not working" - what does trhat mean exactly?

Comment: it's just opening the edge browser with the start tab.

Comment: And if you type file:///c:/ into the browser and navigate to the pdf, what url do you get, and does it open in browser or try to download?

Comment: When I open a pdf in the browser, the URL I get is "file:///C:/Desktop/sample.pdf". And it will open the pdf, not download.

Comment: What is the overall goal here? What problem are you ultimately trying to solve? (This is the way you chose to solve it, and this way has a problem – are you trying to open this PDF because it's a help document for your locally installed app?)

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the problem on my machine, it seems that you want to open a PDF file in Edge browser from another browser. As far as I know, Edge browser URL protocol no longer works for local files, only for http/https.

As a workaround, I suggest you could upload the local pdf file to the internet, such as OneDrive. Then, we could get the shared link and use it with the Edge URL protocol.

Sample code as below:

```
<a href="microsoft-edge:https://research.google.com/pubs/archive/44678.pdf">Link</a>
```